# Getting good at Lumines

Tags: lumines

I see people with scores of 189+ on the 60 second time attack.  I'm lucky to break 60 blocks.  What are some concepts those people are using to be so successful?

This is the Steam version of the game.

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest challenge is connecting to the beat of the music. When I first started playing, I was constantly trying to match as many pieces as quickly as possible. There is a sweet spot to timing the matched blocks to the bar that sweeps across the screen to 'clear' the blocks. And to agree with @KatieK, playing Puzzle mode helped train my technique on how to stack & plan for future block drops. (My experience has been limited to the PSP & the XBLA versions of the game.)

Answer (score 1):

Play Puzzle mode.  Each of these very small levels will teach a basic technique such as what to do with single pieces, and how to make a disappearing tower.

For Time Attack mode, I find my most successful strategy is to focus on many very small cubes.

In other modes, learn how to work with the time-line in different levels.  In some levels it moves very fast, so you won't have much opportunity to build long combos.